# How to make the output print the first position of every three identical numbers?

Tags: c#

How to make the output print the first position of every three identical numbers? (in this case 4 {position number 3} and 7  {position number 8)?

```
int counter = new int();
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,7};
         
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
  if (arr[i] == arr[i+1]) // it says "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
  {
    counter++;
    if (counter == 2)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " "); 
    }
  }
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You have `i < arr.Length` in the loop. When i == arr.Length-1, it means that arr[i+1] goes "out" of the array.

Comment: Could you explain further?

1. You want 3 identical numbers in a row (2,3,4,4,4) or just 3 in random places (2,3,4,5,1,4,4) and

2. you want all numbers that appear 3 times or the number is specified by the user?

Comment: You should do `i < arr.Length - 2` in your for loop.

Comment: i mean that i want that the output will give me where there are trio. in my example position 3 and 8

Comment: just to change ( i < arr.Length - 2 ) in the for loop and everything else leav the same ?because it doesnt seem to wotk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must iterate through you array and check for equality 3 numbers in a row

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7 };

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 2; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1] && arr[i] == arr[i + 2])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Trio is at:" + i + " Value is" + arr[i]);
    }
}

Console.ReadKey();
```